# Can you have a list of operators as a parameter?

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, parameters

I am creating a report where the user can select which operator they want to use in the query to compare two numbers. Can this be done in SSRS?

I was thinking it might be best to use a `case` statement. Something like this where `total_count` is a field and `:Total_Allowed_Parm` is a number they choose from a dropdown menu.

```
WHERE total_count CASE  
                     WHEN :Operator_Parm = '=' THEN =
                     WHEN :Operator_Parm = '<' THEN <
                     WHEN :Operator_Parm = '>' THEN >
                     WHEN :Operator_Parm = '<=' THEN <=
                     WHEN :Operator_Parm = '>=' THEN >=
                     ELSE <>
                  END  :Total_Allowed_Parm
```

Comment: The documentation may tell you: [CASE **Expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96). And the definition of  [**expression**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Expressions.html#GUID-68789A5C-B142-496F-ADEE-837F75F95B2B): *An expression is a combination of one or more values, operators, and SQL functions **that evaluates to a value***

Comment: What is SSRS? Isn't that something related to SQL Server? If it is, then what does that have to do with Oracle?

Comment: @mathguy SSRS is a BI reporting tool, Oracle is a backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oracle have no Boolean datatype and `case` is an expression, you need to do all that checks manually. Like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where
  case
    when :Operator_Parm = '=' and total_count = :Total_Allowed_Parm then 1
    when :Operator_Parm = '>=' and total_count >= :Total_Allowed_Parm then 1
    when :Operator_Parm = '>' and total_count > :Total_Allowed_Parm then 1
    /*Other comparisons go here*/
  end is not null
```

Please note, that all  the above does not take care of nulls: in SQL nothing (including `null` itself) is neither equal, nor not equal to `null`.

Alternatively there may be some mechanism in SSRS, that may directly embed (do SQL injection) selected value inside SQL text, but I do not know.

Comment: @user3691608 Possibly a better and more clear way is MT0's answer: just put the same conditions used in `case` into the `where` clause combined by `or`.

Comment: I got this to work. Had to put ELSE 0 END = 1 at the end of my CASE.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a `CASE` expression:

```sql
WHERE (:Operator_Parm = '=' AND total_count = :Total_Allowed_Parm)
OR    (:Operator_Parm = '<' AND total_count < :Total_Allowed_Parm)
OR    (:Operator_Parm = '>' AND total_count > :Total_Allowed_Parm)
OR    (:Operator_Parm = '<=' AND total_count <= :Total_Allowed_Parm)
OR    (:Operator_Parm = '>=' AND total_count >= :Total_Allowed_Parm)
OR    (:Operator_Parm NOT IN ('=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=')
       AND total_count <> :Total_Allowed_Parm)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the dataset query's Expression Builder to put the operator directly in the SQL.

```
="SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE total_count " & Parameters!OPERATOR.Value & " " & Parameters!Total_Allowed_Parm.Value
```

This does leave open the possibility of SQL injection but if you use a parameter with a list of values to select, the users won't be able to type anything into the parameter.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I could do this because the line is in the WHERE clause of the SQL.

Comment: @user3691608 - I updated the expression to include the second parameter that I missed before.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are comparing a total_count (coming from some place - perhaps a subquery) to an input value, `:total_allowed_parm`, and you want the comparison to use a comparison operator also passed in as an input value, `:operator_parm`?

You can do this using XML tools, specifically the XQuery expression evaluation. Something like this (using the standard `EMPLOYEES` table in the `HR` schema for illustration):

Let's see how many new hires were made in each year. (Not conditional yet.)

```
select extract(year from hire_date) as yr, count(*) as total_count
from   hr.employees
group  by extract(year from hire_date)
order  by yr
;

  YR TOTAL_COUNT
---- -----------
2001           1
2002           7
2003           6
2004          10
2005          29
2006          24
2007          19
2008          11
```

Now let's pass in a comparison operator and a comparison number. For example, we allow the user (by choosing `>=` and `10`) to find in which years there were 10 or more hires.

First, declare and initialize the bind variables (using SQL*Plus, or - in my case - the "run as script" facility in SQL Developer):

```
variable total_allowed_parm number
execute :total_allowed_parm := 10

variable operator_parm varchar2(2)
execute :operator_parm := '>='
```

Then here is the query. In the `with` clause, first I have - as a subquery - the query shown above: counting hires by year. The second subquery prepares the XQuery expression for evaluation.

```
with
  prep (yr, total_count) as (
    select extract(year from hire_date), count(*)
    from   hr.employees
    group  by extract(year from hire_date)
  )
, xml_prep (yr, total_count, comparison) as (
    select yr, total_count, total_count || :operator_parm || :total_allowed_parm
    from   prep
  )
select yr, total_count
from   xml_prep
where  xmlcast(xmlquery(comparison returning content) as varchar2(5)) = 'true'
order  by yr
;

  YR TOTAL_COUNT
---- -----------
2004          10
2005          29
2006          24
2007          19
2008          11
```

Remember, if you are doing this in SQL Developer and you define and initialize the bind variables as I have shown, you need to run the SQL statement "as script" (F5) - or else you will need to enter the binds at the prompt (if you run "as statement" with Ctrl+Enter).